# Transform query that works in SQLite into something that works in Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

```
Message.order("created_at DESC").where(user_id: current_user.id).group(:sender_id, :receiver_id).count
```

Works with my dev environment SQLite3 for a Rails 3.2 app but fails when pushed to Heroku using Postgres with this error:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR: column "messages.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

It seems it wants `:created_at` in the query. Unable to come up with anything. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try adding :created_at to the query, per its desire? `Message.order("created_at DESC").where(user_id: current_user.id).group(:sender_id, :receiver_id, :created_at).count`

Comment: @hd1: While this will make Postgre accept the query, the results will probably not be the desired ones: 2 messages from user 1 to user 2 won't be grouped together unless they were sent at the exact time, which is rather unlikely (and probably not the wanted behaviour).

Comment: Yes to both comments above. Adding :created_at will make the query work for Postgres but the result is not correct. In effect it does not group anymore as every message has a unique :created_at column.

Comment: @slindsey3000: Did the answer I posted below not work for you?

Comment: I am waiting for traffic on my site to die down a little bit sir then will push it up to production. I have to have a Rails.env flag because I run SQLite local. Will advise. Thank you sir. Hope it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL can't figure out how to order by your `created_at`.

Suppose that you find 2 groups of `(:sender_id, :receiver_id)`, for instance `[1, 2]` and
`[1, 3]`.
Now suppose that in the first group you have 2 messages, one from 1 day ago and one from 1 minute ago. And let's say you have 1 message in the second group from 12 hours ago.
Then `ORDER BY created_at DESC` doesn't make any sense: do you take the message from 1 day ago as the `created_at` of the first group (hence the first group appears after the second one), or the one from 1 minute ago (in which case the first group now appears first)?

That's why PostgreSQL says that you need to either have `created_at` in the `GROUP BY` (in which case you now have **3 different group**, as the first one is now split in two), or you need to use an aggregate function to transform multiple values of `created_at` into a single one.

---

This will run (I don't know what you expect the results to be, you might not want to use `MAX(created_at)` ! You can find a list of PostgreSQL's *aggregate functions* [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html)) :

```
Message.order("MAX(created_at) DESC")
       .where(user_id: current_user.id)
       .group(:sender_id, :receiver_id)
       .count
```